# access the value of array by pointer in CLR

Tags: arrays, opencv, visual-c++, c++-cli, clr

I have a problem regarding accessing the value of array by pointer.
In native C++ language, I can access the element by the following code

```
int a[]={1,2,3};
cout<<*(a+1);
```

So, I can get "2".

However, when I use C++ CLR and openCV 2.4.7, there is an error. The code as bellow.

```
cv::Mat a;
cout<<*(a+1);
```

I don't know how to deal with it after searching some websites. Wish anyone can help me. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you declare `int a[]` you should ask yourself what is a?

the answer is: a is array of integers. it is also the address of the first integer in the array.

so when you call `*(a+1);`

it been interpreted as:

1. take the address of `a` and add size of int to it (a+1).
2. go to the result address and take its content.

when you declare `cv::Mat a;`
it is not an array. a is an object, not an address.

now `(a+1)` has any  meaning only when `cv::Mat` has the `operator +`. otherwise it will result an error. even if it has the `operator +` I'll guess the return value will be a `cv::Mat` not an integer.

`*(a+1)` has no meaning since the result is not an address.

And finally ,to print it with a `cout` it also has to implement the stream operator `operator<<` with argument of `cv::Mat`.

Comment: array->pointer decay is rather different from taking the address of the array.  If you did take the address, a subsequent `+1` would advance by `sizeof (int[3])`.

Comment: I have solved this problem after utilizing the above suggestions. Thank you very much.